# Is it possible to set user permissions for different namespaces in google datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-console

I have a namespace that store some important information and I want keep permissions restrict only to this namespace. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict access to a Datastore namespace. For example, in Datastore the permissions are project-wide, this means that you cannot give read access to only a specific set of namespaces/entities, but you give `datastore.entities.get` permissions to an user, and he will be able to read any entity in Datastore in your project.

As a side note, in Google Cloud Platform, all the data is encrypted by default before being written into the disk (see [Encryption at Rest](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/), and the [Datastore Encryption documentation on this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/encryption-at-rest)), however, the values will be displayed in the Cloud Console, given that at least an user has view access to Datastore, unencrypted.

To workaround this, if you don't want sensitive data to be displayed to users with general read access to Datastore in your project, you could encrypt your data in your side before writing it into datastore, for example using [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), although this methods require of Third Party tools in order to encrypt the data, and falls out of GCP support.